# How to use regression when assumption of constant variance, Linearity and normality are not met

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I need to build a model that predicts a response based on 2 predicting variables. I am using R as the software.

I have tried the below methods with given R squared values:
1. Linear Regression - 0.556
2. Decision Tree Regression - 0.608
3. linear Regression (after removing outliers using the cooks distance method) - 0.6068
4. Polynomial regression (power of 3) on data without outliers - 0.608

when I check the assumptions, I see the below graph - 
[we can see that none of the assumptions seem to be fulfilled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdfhh.png)

is there some different regression model I should use? I have confirmed that the data I am working on is clean.

The summary of output for linear regression is as below

```
Call:
lm(formula = Freight ~ TotalWeight + distance, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1104.56   -60.39   -17.69    28.99  2076.90 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 3.286e+01  7.141e+00   4.601 4.49e-06 ***
TotalWeight 9.666e-02  2.246e-03  43.042  < 2e-16 ***
distance    5.235e-05  2.884e-06  18.152  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 165.1 on 1790 degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.5556,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5551 
F-statistic:  1119 on 2 and 1790 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As we see, both the independent variables have extremely small p values, i.e. they are highly relevant.
The 95% confidence interval is

```
                   2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept) 1.885358e+01 4.686585e+01
TotalWeight 9.225246e-02 1.010612e-01
distance    4.669026e-05 5.800235e-05
```

Is there any method I can use to better fit the data.

Comment: This is almost certainly a question for Cross Validate. The below link on data transformation might get you started: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24227/how-to-choose-the-best-transformation-to-achieve-linearity

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: Thanks , I am not sure if I am allowed to share the data link. Here is a scatter plot matrix of the data, I hope it helps visualize the trends. Freight is the dependent variable. Distance and weights are independent.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GnggDma36ch22Ee7upxmS_JnZWLCUnhM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [Many resources out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=when+regression+assumptions+not+met).